# PySpark ML: Get KMeans cluster statistics

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-spark-ml

I have built a KMeansModel. My results are stored in a PySpark DataFrame called 
`transformed`.

(a) How do I interpret the contents of `transformed`?

(b) How do I create one or more Pandas DataFrame from `transformed` that would show summary statistics for each of the 13 features for each of the 14 clusters?

```python
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
# Trains a k-means model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(14).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(X_spark_scaled) # Fits a model to the input dataset with optional parameters.

transformed = model.transform(X_spark_scaled).select("features", "prediction") # X_spark_scaled is my PySpark DataFrame consisting of 13 features
transformed.show(5, truncate = False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|features                                                                                                                            |prediction|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|(14,[4,5,7,8,9,13],[1.0,1.0,485014.0,0.25,2.0,1.0])                                                                                 |12        |
|(14,[2,7,8,9,12,13],[1.0,2401233.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                                                                                |2         |
|(14,[2,4,5,7,8,9,13],[0.3333333333333333,0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666,2429111.0,0.9166666666666666,1.3333333333333333,3.0])|2         |
|(14,[4,5,7,8,9,12,13],[1.0,1.0,2054748.0,0.15384615384615385,11.0,1.0,1.0])                                                         |11        |
|(14,[2,7,8,9,13],[1.0,43921.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                                                                                         |1         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

As an aside, I found from another SO post that I can map the features to their names like below. It would be nice to have summary statistics (mean, median, std, min, max) for each feature of each cluster in one or more Pandas dataframes.

```python
attr_list = [attr for attr in chain(*transformed.schema['features'].metadata['ml_attr']['attrs'].values())]
attr_list
```

Per request in the comments, here is a snapshot consisting of 2 records of the data (don't want to provide too many records -- proprietary information here)

```python
+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|device_type_robot_pct|device_type_smart_tv_pct|device_type_desktop_pct|device_type_tablet_pct|device_type_mobile_pct|device_type_mobile_persist_pct|visitors_seen_with_anonymiser_pct|ip_time_span|          ip_weight|mean_ips_per_visitor|visitors_seen_with_multi_country_pct|international_visitors_pct|visitors_seen_with_multi_ua_pct|count_tuids_on_ip|            features|      scaledFeatures|
+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  0.0|                     0.0|                    0.0|                   0.0|                   1.0|                           1.0|                              0.0|    485014.0|               0.25|                 2.0|                                 0.0|                       0.0|                            0.0|              1.0|(14,[4,5,7,8,9,13...|(14,[4,5,7,8,9,13...|
|                  0.0|                     0.0|                    1.0|                   0.0|                   0.0|                           0.0|                              0.0|   2401233.0|                1.0|                 1.0|                                 0.0|                       0.0|                            1.0|              1.0|(14,[2,7,8,9,12,1...|(14,[2,7,8,9,12,1...|
```

Comment: Can you also show a sample of the initial data `X_spark_scaled`, please?

Comment: I would rather use sklearn than pyspark. Run a benchmark, which is faster? Which is easier to use? Which finds better clusters?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I actually tried sklearn, but I have about 600bn records and that is far too many for sklearn to be able to bring into memory

Comment: @desertnaut will do later today

Comment: For kmeans, that size doesn't make that much sense anymore. (Plus, you probably have problems getting a statistically meaningful result anyway). A sample is enough. And Spark kmeans is so incredibly slow... I have yet to see a use case where Spark on the entire data would give a better result in reasonable time than a *better* kmeans on a single-node on "as much data as you can fit into one bodes memory".

Comment: @Anony-Mousse typo. *600mn. I'm using PySpark's MLlib and it was fast enough (30-90 minutes? ran in the background on our computing cluster). regardless, this convo is a tangent relative to the question I've posed

Comment: 600m, that fits into main memory of a single server. Did you run until *convergence*? (setEpsilon 0)? 'cause if you stop early, then you really can just use a sample right away to get equally good results.

Comment: It's not just "tangential" to your question: pyspark is much more limited than sklearn, and if you'd use sklearn instead of pyspark (which isn't native Python), the question would be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Anony-Mousse has commented, (Py)Spark ML is indeed *much* more limited that scikit-learn or other similar packages, and such functionality is not trivial; nevertheless, here is a way to get what you want (cluster statistics):

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

# toy data - 5-d features including sparse vectors
df = spark.createDataFrame(
 [(Vectors.sparse(5,[(0, 164.0),(1,520.0)]), 1.0),
  (Vectors.dense([519.0,2723.0,0.0,3.0,4.0]), 1.0),
  (Vectors.sparse(5,[(0, 2868.0), (1, 928.0)]), 1.0),
  (Vectors.sparse(5,[(0, 57.0), (1, 2715.0)]), 0.0),
  (Vectors.dense([1241.0,2104.0,0.0,0.0,2.0]), 1.0)],
 ["features", "target"])

df.show()
# +--------------------+------+ 
# |            features|target| 
# +--------------------+------+ 
# |(5,[0,1],[164.0,5...|   1.0|
# |[519.0,2723.0,0.0...|   1.0| 
# |(5,[0,1],[2868.0,...|   1.0|
# |(5,[0,1],[57.0,27...|   0.0| 
# |[1241.0,2104.0,0....|   1.0|
# +--------------------+------+

kmeans = KMeans(k=3, seed=1)
model = kmeans.fit(df.select('features'))

transformed = model.transform(df).select("features", "prediction")
transformed.show()
# +--------------------+----------+
# |            features|prediction|
# +--------------------+----------+
# |(5,[0,1],[164.0,5...|         1| 
# |[519.0,2723.0,0.0...|         2|
# |(5,[0,1],[2868.0,...|         0|
# |(5,[0,1],[57.0,27...|         2|
# |[1241.0,2104.0,0....|         2|
# +--------------------+----------+
```

Up to here, and regarding your first question:

> How do I interpret the contents of `transformed`?

The `features` column is just a replication of the same column in your original data.

The `prediction` column is the cluster to which the respective data record belongs to; in my example, with 5 data records and `k=3` clusters, I end up with 1 record in cluster #0, 1 record in cluster #1, and 3 records in cluster #2.

Regarding your second question:

> How do I create one or more Pandas DataFrame from `transformed` that would show summary statistics for each of the 13 features for each of the 14 clusters?

(Note: seems you have *14* features and not 13...)

This is a good example of a seemingly simple task for which, unfortunately, PySpark does not provide ready functionality - not least because all features are grouped in a *single* vector `features`; to do that, we must first "disassemble" `features`, effectively coming up with the *invert* operation of [`VectorAssembler`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler).

The only way I can presently think of is to revert temporarily to an RDD and perform a `map` operation [EDIT: this is not really necessary - see UPDATE below]; here is an example with my cluster #2 above, which contains both dense and sparse vectors:

```python
# keep only cluster #2:
cl_2 = transformed.filter(transformed.prediction==2)
cl_2.show() 
# +--------------------+----------+ 
# |            features|prediction|
# +--------------------+----------+
# |[519.0,2723.0,0.0...|         2|
# |(5,[0,1],[57.0,27...|         2|
# |[1241.0,2104.0,0....|         2| 
# +--------------------+----------+

# set the data dimensionality as a parameter:
dimensionality = 5

cluster_2 = cl_2.drop('prediction').rdd.map(lambda x: [float(x[0][i]) for i in range(dimensionality)]).toDF(schema=['x'+str(i) for i in range(dimensionality)])
cluster_2.show()
# +------+------+---+---+---+ 
# |    x0|    x1| x2| x3| x4|
# +------+------+---+---+---+
# | 519.0|2723.0|0.0|3.0|4.0|
# |  57.0|2715.0|0.0|0.0|0.0| 
# |1241.0|2104.0|0.0|0.0|2.0|
# +------+------+---+---+---+
```

(If you have your initial data in a Spark dataframe `initial_data`, you can change the last part to `toDF(schema=initial_data.columns)`, in order to keep the original feature names.)

From this point, you could either convert `cluster_2` dataframe to a pandas one (if it fits in your memory), or use the [`describe()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe) function of Spark dataframes to get your summary statistics:

```python
cluster_2.describe().show()
# result:
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---+------------------+---+ 
|summary|               x0|               x1| x2|                x3| x4|
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---+------------------+---+ 
|  count|                3|                3|  3|                 3|  3|
|   mean|605.6666666666666|           2514.0|0.0|               1.0|2.0|
| stddev|596.7389155512932|355.0929455790413|0.0|1.7320508075688772|2.0|
|    min|             57.0|           2104.0|0.0|               0.0|0.0|
|    max|           1241.0|           2723.0|0.0|               3.0|4.0|
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---+------------------+---+
```

Using the above code with `dimensionality=14` in your case should do the job...

Annoyed with all these (arguably useless) significant digits in `mean` and `stddev`? As a bonus, here is a small utility function I had come up [some time ago](https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-dataframes-from-csv-files/) for a pretty summary:

```python
def prettySummary(df):
    """ Neat summary statistics of a Spark dataframe
    Args:
        pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame (df): input dataframe
    Returns:
        pandas.core.frame.DataFrame: a pandas dataframe with the summary statistics of df
    """
    import pandas as pd
    temp = df.describe().toPandas()
    temp.iloc[1:3,1:] = temp.iloc[1:3,1:].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
    return temp

stats_df = prettySummary(cluster_2)
stats_df
# result:
    summary     x0       x1   x2   x3   x4
 0  count        3        3    3    3    3 
 1   mean   605.67 2,514.00 0.00 1.00 2.00 
 2 stddev   596.74   355.09 0.00 1.73 2.00 
 3    min     57.0   2104.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
 4    max   1241.0   2723.0  0.0  3.0  4.0
```

---

**UPDATE**: Thinking of it again, and seeing your sample data, I came up with a more straightforward solution, without the need to invoke an intermediate RDD (an operation that one would arguably prefer to avoid, if possible)...

The key observation is the complete contents of `transformed`, i.e. *without* the `select` statements; keeping the same toy dataset as above, we get:

```python
transformed = model.transform(df)  # no 'select' statements
transformed.show()
# +--------------------+------+----------+
# |            features|target|prediction| 
# +--------------------+------+----------+
# |(5,[0,1],[164.0,5...|   1.0|         1|
# |[519.0,2723.0,0.0...|   1.0|         2|
# |(5,[0,1],[2868.0,...|   1.0|         0|
# |(5,[0,1],[57.0,27...|   0.0|         2|
# |[1241.0,2104.0,0....|   1.0|         2|
# +--------------------+------+----------+
```

As you can see, whatever other columns are present in the dataframe `df` to be transformed (just one in my case - `target`) just "pass-through" the transformation procedure and end-up being present in the final outcome...

Hopefully you start getting the idea: if `df` contains your initial 14 features, each one in a separate column, plus a 15th column named `features` (roughly as shown in your sample data, but without the last column), then the following code:

```python
kmeans = KMeans().setK(14)
model = kmeans.fit(df.select('features'))
transformed = model.transform(df).drop('features')
```

will leave you with a Spark dataframe `transformed` containing 15 columns, i.e. your initial 14 features plus a `prediction` column with the corresponding cluster number.

From this point, you can proceed as I have shown above to `filter` specific clusters from `transformed` and get your summary statistics, but you'll have avoided the (costly...) conversion to intermediate temporary RDDs, thus keeping all your operations in the more efficient context of Spark dataframes...

Comment: "PySpark does not provide ready functionality. . ." Totally agree. We love sklearn, but our huge data volume forces us to use PySpark. "coming up with the invert operation of VectorAssembler" yes, that succinctly specifies exactly what I needed to do. Thank you very much for this detailed and helpful answer.

Comment: @user2205916 You are very welcome; re "invert operation of VectorAssembler" - as I explain in the update, turns out it is not necessary if you already have the initial features

Comment: yeah, so I was really asking the wrong question in my mind, and the wrong question on here (#2). But you gave the right answer! My fault for not fully understanding I was filtering out my initial features with the `select` and not knowing they were there to begin with. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2205916 don't blame yourself - even in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans), they *always* accompany `transform` with `select("features", "prediction")`; no accident that myself initially fell for the RDD solution...